# Make bounce animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to do bounce animation of layer.

I have done that layer comes from right to center, now I would like to move it a little back and then back to center. That would create bounce effect.

I was thinking that I can do it with a translate like this:

```
<translate
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />

<translate
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />

<translate
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromXDelta="70%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />
```

Well this code does not working, only thing I can achieve is that Layer comes from left to center, and then animation stops.

I cannot use this code: because it does not achieve what I want

```
setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this,
                        android.R.anim.bounce_interpolator));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you specified duration for your animation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [BounceInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/BounceInterpolator.html) to have this effect. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View) contain a very good description how to use it in XML. Just have a animation xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <!-- Use your working translate animation here-->
    <translate
        android:duration="900"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

Comment: thx, for the offered solution, but its not what Im looking for. This animation keep bouncing. I need only "one" bounce.

Comment: Create your own interpolator then, or use an accelerate-decelerate with repeat=1 + reverse (which looks "similar")

Comment: i believe what you want is an overshoot interpolator @5er https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UL7PXdJ6-E

Answer (score 4):

use this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

This will show bounce effect with scale ,different from translate,(*fits better in some situations*),for more check [THIS](https://gagandroid.blogspot.in/2015/03/animation-in-android-using-xml.html) out..

Answer (score 4):

Add code on button or image click

```
    final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.bounce);
    // Use bounce interpolator with amplitude 0.1 and frequency 15
    MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.1, 15);
    myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    imgVoiceSearch.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

Add this class

```
public class MyBounceInterpolator implements android.view.animation.Interpolator {
private double mAmplitude = 1;
private double mFrequency = 10;

public MyBounceInterpolator(double amplitude, double frequency) {
    mAmplitude = amplitude;
    mFrequency = frequency;
}

public float getInterpolation(float time) {
    return (float) (-1 * Math.pow(Math.E, -time / mAmplitude) *
            Math.cos(mFrequency * time) + 1);
}
}
```