# Android animation with delay xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I am trying to setup a little animation of bouncing through a xml file.
The idea is that the view will go up 5dp and then back down (reverse) and then wait 2 seconds and do that again... infinitely.

My code is this but somehow after the first anim, it restarts the position at 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate
    android:startOffset="2000"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:toYDelta="-5" />

<translate
    android:startOffset="2500"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="-5"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

Any idea what I should do?

Also if I am doing it with a single translate and reverse then it waits the 2 seconds to do the reverse... I want to do normal-reverse and then wait 2 seconds:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate
    android:startOffset="2000"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode = "reverse"
    android:toYDelta="-5" />

</set>
```

Comment: This might have help you [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23940867/9254960)